# React + FontAwesome + Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to learn React and Bootstrap at the same time. I am a beginner.

My issue is that I am trying to display a FontAwesome icon within a React application using the FontAwesome component.  I have a Pro license for FontAwesome and have followed their directions on setting up the dependencies.  My package.json contains the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.33-beta1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.0.0-beta1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

When I attempt to use an icon in a component like below:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faUser } from "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons";

function Header(){
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>My Header</h1>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="red" size="6x" />
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

I get an error:

**Error: Cannot find module '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'**

When I review the error bodies below the header they all seem to point to bootstrap.

```
__webpack_require__
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1069:18
__webpack_require__
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/work/RTS/rts_react/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
```

I have looked through my project which is still small because I am just beginning and I can't find any reference to the Free icons for FontAwesome.  I am at a loss and not sure what to even ask.  Is there a reference to the free icons within the Bootstrap React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to FontAwesome's React documentation, you need to install `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`, too, before adding additional styles.

Run `npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` and try again.

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.  I did not think I needed it because to me the documentation reads that you install whatever icon packs you want to use.  I obviously did not read that right.  Thank you very much for your help.